# Como crear sliding por debajo del toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, menú

Quiero que quede un menu lateral y q se deslize cada vez q aprete sobre el icono del menu pero haciendolo de la forma que lo estoy haciendo me muestra siempre el menu lateral y no se ocultar

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape_green"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/transfer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:onClick="goToTransfer"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:text="prueba"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_separator_with"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape_green"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beneficiaries"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:onClick="goToLinkBeneficiaries"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:text="prueba 2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_separator_with"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape_green"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/personalInformation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:onClick="goToPersonalInformation"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:text="prueba 3"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_separator_with"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape_green"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/changeEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/slide_menu_margin"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_config"
                android:onClick="goToChangeEmail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/slide_menu_padding"
                android:text="prueba 4"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closesession"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_principal"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape_green"
            android:onClick="closeSession"
            android:text="@string/button_closesession" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Comment: Explica mas tu pregunta para que sea mas facil entenderla, puedes editarla y agregar mas información

Comment: Hola Jonatan veo que sos nuevo en stack , por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida! :)

Comment: Muchas gracias! ajuste las sugerencias!